# How to share scope between parent and child directives

Tags: angularjs, scope, angular-directive

I am creating a directive where two other child directives use it is functionalities but I need a help to know how to make the scope shared between the parent and the child directive

**Parent directive**

```
MetronicApp.directive('atmSearchComponent', function () {

    function AtmSearchComponentController(scope) {
        // initialize scope
    }

    AtmSearchComponentController.prototype.search = function () {
       scope.mainGridOptions.dataSource.page(1);
       reset();
    }

    AtmSearchComponentController.prototype.clearSearch = function () {
       scope.data.basicSearch = {};
       scope.data.advancedSearch = {};
    }

    AtmSearchComponentController.prototype.keyPressSearch = function (keyEvent) {
       if (keyEvent.which === 13) {
           keyEvent.preventDefault()
           scope.search();
       }
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: ['$scope', AtmSearchComponentController],
        scope: {}
    };

});
```

**Child directive**

```
MetronicApp.directive('atmsQuerySelector', function ($log, $parse, $timeout, $http, $uibModal) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: false,
        scope: {},
        require: ['^atmSearchComponent', 'ngModel'],
        templateUrl: "/apps/framework/templates/atmsSelector.view",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, controllersArray) {

            scope.search = controllersArray[0].search;

            clearSearch = controllersArray[0].clearSearch;

            scope.keyPressSearch = controllersArray[0].keyPressSearch;
        },
    }
});
```

but when I call the search method I get the following error

> ReferenceError: scope is not defined
>       at n.AtmSearchComponentController.search (directives.js:8)

Comment: Please create a plnkr or fiddle to reproduce it.

Comment: I guess you are creating isolated scope for each directive. Could you please remove `scope:{}` from second directive and check.